# number of points with distance $\ge \delta$ that can fit inside a square with edge length $\delta$

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

I want to prove the claim that if you have a square with edge length $\delta$ and you want to fit as many points, each pair has distance $\ge \delta$, inside that square, You can fit at most 4, and they have to be on the corners of the square. I wrote a proof and I want someone to approve or dis approve it. In the pictures, look at the purple points, they're the ones I'm examining.
Of course I'll be glad for any suggestions. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9M2x.png)

[image]

Comment: "This necessarily means that at least one edge of the quadrilateral is of length $< \delta$" because why?

Comment: possible explanation would be that the bounded Quadrilateral diagonals are shorter then the square's diagonals. This means, if we divide the Quadrilateral to two rectangles, that their height is shorter then $\frac{\sqrt{2}*\delta}{2}$ so their area combined is $\lt 2\times\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\delta}{4}\times\sqrt2\delta\right) = 2\times\frac{\delta^2}{2} = \delta^2$
Is this true?

Comment: Whether it is true or not, it doesn't prove what you need it to. For your proof to work, you need that a quadrilateral with all pairs of points (including diagonals) at least $\delta$ apart must have area of at least $\delta^2$. Showing it to be less than $\delta^2$ doesn't help at all.

Comment: You're right. What if I continue down this path and prove that at least one triangle inside the Quadrilateral has to have at least one edge shorter then $\delta$ because it's base is shorter then $\sqrt2\delta$ and it's area is smaller then $\frac{\delta^2}{2}$? Or you can point me in another direction if you have one.. Thank you

Comment: That will work if you can show it. Another direction that comes to mind is (1) show the quadrilateral must be convex (2) show that a convex quadrilateral in the square can be enlarged by moving any points not on boundary to the boundary (3) show that largest quadrilateral with points on boundary occurs when the points are in the corner. The last step can be shown analytically.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is: assume there are points inside the square and all edges between them have length $\delta$, show the edges can be enlarged of we move the points to the square's boundary, show they could be farther enlarged if we move them to the corners, now their length is $\delta$ contradiction - their length not on the corners was less than $\delta$?

Comment: No need to cast it as a contradiction. Just start with the assumption you have 4 pts with all distances $\ge \delta$, then show that having vertices on the edges, and then in the corners lengthens the edges. Since the final edges are $\ge$ the initial edges, but are also $= \delta$, the initial edges must be $\delta$ as well. (By the way, you might as well set $\delta = 1$. The problem is scalable, so solution for $1$ is a solution for all $\delta$.)

Comment: But I want to prove that placing the points on the corners is the **only** way that they all have distance $\delta$ from each other. Your proof leaves the possibility for other arrangements.